# can we get any relation between the eigenvectors of thee two matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If two matrices commute then they share same eigen vectors

Comment: If all $\lambda_i$ are distinct, we can guarantee that the eigenvectors of $A$ are also eigenvectors of $M$.

Comment: So you're saying that $\lambda_i \neq \lambda_j$ for all $i,j$, and that $n$ is the size of the matrix?

Comment: Doesn't matter; we necessarily know the eigenvectors of $M$, now. We got "lucky" in that $11^T$ commutes with $A$.

Comment: I could later today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that because $A$ is size $n$ with $n$ distinct eigenvectors, $Av = \lambda_i v$ implies that $v$ is a multiple of $v_i$.

Thus, for every $i$, we note that
$$
A(Mv_i) = MAv_i = \lambda_i (Mv_i)
$$
which implies that $Mv_i$ is a multiple of $v_i$, which implies that $v_i$ is an eigenvector of $M$.